# std::setprecision sets the number of significant figures. How do I use iomanip to set the precision?

Tags: c++, iomanip

I have always found iomanip confusing and counter intuitive. I need help.

A quick internet search finds (https://www.vedantu.com/maths/precision) "We thus consider precision as the maximum number of significant digits **after the decimal point** in a decimal number" (the emphasis is mine). That matches my understanding too. However I wrote a test program and:

```
stm << std::setprecision(3) << 5.12345678;
std::cout << "5.12345678: " << stm.str() << std::endl;
stm.str("");

stm << std::setprecision(3) << 25.12345678;
std::cout << "25.12345678: " << stm.str() << std::endl;
stm.str("");

stm << std::setprecision(3) << 5.1;
std::cout << "5.1: " << stm.str() << std::endl;
stm.str("");
```

outputs:

```
5.12345678: 5.12
25.12345678: 25.1
5.1: 5.1
```

If the precision is 3 then the output should be:

```
5.12345678: 5.123
25.12345678: 25.123
5.1: 5.1
```

Clearly the C++ standard has a different interpretation of the meaning of "precision" as relates to floating point numbers.

If I do:

```
stm.setf(std::ios::fixed, std::ios::floatfield);
```

then the first two values are formatted correctly, but the last comes out as `5.100`.

How do I set the precision without padding?

Comment: Excellent question. Every time I tell my students about this behavior of setprecision, I keep wondering how would I go about if I needed the given precision AFTER the dot but without the trailing zeros... I then quickly forget about this by the end of the lecture. Hopefully I will finally learn the answer in the answers section to this question.

Comment: Careful: `5.1` is not exactly representable as a binary floating point number

Comment: @Caleth. Really? I think you are wrong. `std::cout << "5.1: " << (double)5.1 << std::endl;` prints exactly "5.1: 5.1". No error at all. Ditto with float.

Comment: You get about [~16 decimal places.](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/526ab0ef3d9b89fe)

Comment: @AlastairG: Really.  `(double)5.1` is actually `2871044762448691 * 2^-49` which is `5.0999999999999996447286321199499070644378662109375`   This page is helpful: https://www.exploringbinary.com/floating-point-converter/

Comment: So the default precision in the standard library is less than 16  then. Thus to all intents and purposes, unless dealing with some very accurate mathematics, there is nothing to be careful about. I think 5.1 is perfectly adequate for my example here.

Comment: @AlastairG according to [this](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ios_base/precision) the default precision is 6

Comment: @Doch88 it's the precision of _output_, not the precision of representation.

Comment: @Ruslan that is obvious

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Solution 1

You can try using this workaround:

```
decltype(std::setprecision(1)) setp(double number, int p) {
    int e = static_cast<int>(std::abs(number));
    e = e != 0? static_cast<int>(std::log10(e)) + 1 + p : p;
    while(number != 0.0 && static_cast<int>(number*=10) == 0 && e > 1) 
        e--; // for numbers like 0.001: those zeros are not treated as digits by setprecision.
    return std::setprecision(e);
}
```

And then:

```
auto v = 5.12345678;
stm << setp(v, 3) << v;
```

---

### Solution 2

Another more verbose and elegant solution is to create a struct like this:

```
struct __setp {
    double number;
    bool fixed = false;
    int prec;
};

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const __setp& obj)
{
    if(obj.fixed)
        os << std::fixed;
    else os << std::defaultfloat;
    os.precision(obj.prec);
    os << obj.number; // comment this if you do not want to print immediately the number
    return os;
}

__setp setp(double number, int p) {
     __setp setter;
     setter.number = number;
     
    int e = static_cast<int>(std::abs(number));
    e = e != 0? static_cast<int>(std::log10(e)) + 1 + p : p;
    while(number != 0.0 && static_cast<int>(number*=10) == 0)
        e--; // for numbers like 0.001: those zeros are not treated as digits by setprecision.

    if(e <= 0) {
        setter.fixed = true;
        setter.prec = 1;
    } else
        setter.prec = e;
    return setter;
}
```

Using it like this:

```
auto v = 5.12345678;
stm << setp(v, 3);
```

Comment: I credited you in our codebase plus requested in the comment to upvote this answer. We are a very small company so don't expect too much :P I wish I could upvote this answer more than once.

Answer (score 2):

The fixed format gives almost what you want except that it preserves trailing zeros. There is no built-in way to avoid that but you can easily remove those zeros manually. For example, in C++20 you can do the following using [`std::format`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/format):

```cpp
std::string format_fixed(double d) {
  auto s = fmt::format("{:.3f}", d);
  auto end = s.find_last_not_of('0');
  return end != std::string::npos ? std::string(s.c_str(), end + 1) : s;
}

std::cout << "5.12345678: " << format_fixed(5.12345678) << "\n";
std::cout << "25.12345678: " << format_fixed(25.12345678) << "\n";
std::cout << "5.1: " << format_fixed(5.1) << "\n";
```

Output:

```
5.12345678: 5.123
25.12345678: 25.123
5.1: 5.1
```

The same example with [the {fmt} library](https://github.com/fmtlib/fmt), `std::format` is based on: [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/Yo68xM).

**Disclaimer**: I'm the author of {fmt} and C++20 `std::format`.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can do it nicely. There are two candidate formats: `defaultfloat` and `fixed`. For the former, "precision" is the maximum number of digits, where both sides of the decimal separator count. For the latter "precision" is the exact number of digits *after* the decimal separator.

So your solution, I think, is to use `fixed` format and then manually clear trailing zeros:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <sstream>

void print(const double number)
{
    std::ostringstream stream;
    stream << std::fixed << std::setprecision(3) << number;
    auto string=stream.str();
    while(string.back()=='0')
        string.pop_back();
    if(string.back()=='.') // in case number is integral; beware of localization issues
        string.pop_back();
    std::cout << string << "\n";
}

int main()
{
    print(5.12345678);
    print(25.12345678);
    print(5.1);
}
```